# How to take a photo, save it and get the photo in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, uri, android-camera

I've been searching the simple example to take a photo, and save it using URI and retrieve the photo for image processing , 
I've tried lot of example code, but none of them went smoothly.

Is there anyone have the example code?

Comment: what you have done still?

Comment: there are about 100's of diffrent topics about this question... just search for it!

Answer (score 14):

define a variable like this

```
protected static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
```

Use the code for calling camera from android.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"fname_" +        
                        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and in the class calling this override the onActivityResult function and enter the code below.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            //use imageUri here to access the image

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            Log.e("URI",imageUri.toString());

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            // here you will get the image as bitmap


        } 
          else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           } 
         }


    }
```

Comment: Do you realise, that with the code you have supplied, you are saving the image full sized to the stated uri, BUT, you are retrieving the reduced sized image from the extras, and creating the bitmap from that reduced size image?

Comment: I am retrieving the image from the uri as full sized.  do you want reduced image

Comment: @paulkayuk how do i retrieve a full sized image image instead of a compressed one?

Comment: Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data") is the way to get the thumbnail

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the full-sized image? I would really like to know. I've been searching through stackoverflow threads for a while now and only coming up on these 7 year old threads of people having the same issue with no response...

Answer (score 6):

there are several example to capture image and store it and open it...

[1. Android Camera API - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

[2. Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

[3. Camera Example on Github](https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example)

[4. Another Example](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-camera-example.html)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I was testing some codes from the internet, and couldn't find any. Then, I studied some basics codes from developer.android. After that, I mixed two different codes and my one worked! Here it goes!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int PICTURE_RESULT = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    ContentValues values;
    private Uri file;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap help1;

    ThumbnailUtils thumbnail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        values = new ContentValues();
    }

    public void launch_camera(View v) {
        // the intent is my camera
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //getting uri of the file
        file = Uri.fromFile(getFile());

        //Setting the file Uri to my photo
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,file);

        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
        {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
        }
    }

    //this method will create and return the path to the image file
    private File getFile() {
        File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/From_camera/imagens");// the file path

        //if it doesn't exist the folder will be created
        if(!folder.exists())
        {folder.mkdir();}

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_"+ timeStamp + "_";
        File image_file = null;

        try {
            image_file = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",folder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mCurrentPhotoPath = image_file.getAbsolutePath();
        return image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    help1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),file);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap( thumbnail.extractThumbnail(help1,help1.getWidth(),help1.getHeight()));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the XML files just have a Button and a ImageView
and do not forget to declare in your android manifest the permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
```

for more informations a suggest:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je9bdkdNQqg

Answer (score -1):

please use the following code.

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 



    static String str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = "";
    private static File f;
    private static int Take_Photo = 2;
    private static String str_randomnumber = "";
    static String str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = "";
    public static String str_SaveFolderName;
    private static File wallpaperDirectory;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int storeposition = 0;
    public static GridView gridview;
    public static ImageView imageView;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ccccc);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str_SaveFolderName = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/rajeshsample";
                str_randomnumber = String.valueOf(nextSessionId());
                wallpaperDirectory = new File(str_SaveFolderName);
                if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
                    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = str_randomnumber
                        + ".jpg";
                str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = str_SaveFolderName
                        + "/" + str_randomnumber + ".jpg";
                System.err.println(" str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath  "
                        + str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
                f = new File(str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(
                        MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),
                        Take_Photo);
                System.err.println("f  " + f);
            }
        });
    }


    // used to create randon numbers
    public String nextSessionId() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == Take_Photo) {
            String filePath = null;

            filePath = str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath;
            if (filePath != null) {
                Bitmap faceView = ( new_decode(new File(
                                filePath))); // ========================> good
                                                // lines



                imageView.setImageBitmap(faceView);

            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }
        }
    } 

    public static Bitmap new_decode(File f) {

        // decode image size

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 300;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 1.5;
            height_tmp /= 1.5;
            scale *= 1.5;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        try {

//          return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
//                  null);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
            System.out.println(" IW " + width_tmp);
            System.out.println("IHH " + height_tmp);           
               int iW = width_tmp;
                int iH = height_tmp;

               return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, iW, iH, true);

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            // clearCache();

            // System.out.println("bitmap creating success");
            System.gc();
            return null;
            // System.runFinalization();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            // System.gc();
            // decodeFile(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="photo" >
    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```